# How to take distinct/unique values from arraylist?

Tags: c#, arraylist

Is there possible to take unique values from arraylist in c# ?,Actually I have an arraylist containing values = 100,101,102,101,100,102,103,but i want unique values from this such as 100,101,102,103. So what is c# syntax for this to take distinct/unique values from arralist?

I tried

```
Arraylist Others=new Arraylist(); 
others=TakeanotherValues();
others.Distinct().Toarray();
```

But error is 'System.Collection.ArrayList Does not copntain defination for Distinct'

Comment: Can you post your trial code?

Comment: Arraylist Others=new Arraylist(); others=TakeanotherValues();others.Distinct().Toarray();

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs old days when C# doesn't have _Generics_. Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: When using a linq it still gives an error

Answer (score 7):

Unless you absolutely have to (e.g. because you're using .NET 1), please don't use ArrayList, it's an old non-generic class. Instead, use `List<T>` in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, e.g. `List<int>` or `List<object>` (the latter is functionally equivalent to an ArrayList since you can add anything to it).
In general, don't use anything directly inside `System.Collections` unless you're sure of what you're doing; use the collections in `System.Collections.Generic` instead.

You can use the LINQ method `Distinct()` on your data, but if you want to use an ArrayList you'll first need to cast it to an `IEnumerable<T>` using `Cast<object>()`, like so:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

var distinctItems = myList.Cast<object>().Distinct();
```

This is equivalent to manually creating a set (e.g. `HashSet<object>`), adding each item of your list to it, and them making a list out of that set, since by definition sets do not keep duplicate items (they don't complain if you insert one though, they just ignore it).

Answer (score 5):

You can use Linq:

```
var distinctArraylist = yourArrayList.ToArray().Distinct();
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to loop on the arraylist items, and insert each item in a new Set.
So that the Set data structure ensures the uniqueness of items.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList() {100, 100, 200, 201, 202};
        HashSet<int> uniqueNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach(int number in numbers) {
            uniqueNumbers.Add(number);
        }
        foreach(int number in uniqueNumbers) {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best non-LINQ solution, since it's what `Distinct()` does internally. (here's the [source](http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#4ab583c7d8e84d6d) of the Distinct implementation)

Comment: Thanks @SolalPirelli. Haven't used Linq before since I switched to open source long time ago :)

Answer (score 1):

Since [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>` you would need to cast it before you can apply the regular LINQ operations:

```
var distinctArrayList = new ArrayList((ICollection)myArrayList.Cast<int>().Distinct().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(1);

IEnumerable<int> values = list.Cast<int>().Distinct();
```

Prints out unique values.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
(from obj in _arrayList obj).Distinct();
```

Comment: This won't compile, you're missing a `select`. Also, it's a bit overkill to use LINQ syntax, `Cast<object>` is enough.